# How to encode an decode an Enum with multiple values

Tags: java, enums

I have 2 classes, an enum with an int value and a String value, and a regular class.

The enum class:

```java
public enum LettersEnum{

    A(0, “Letter A”),
    B(1, “Letter B”),
    C(2, “Letter C”);

    private final id;
    private final letter;

    LettersEnum(int id, String letter) {
        this.id = id;
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getLetter() {
        return this.letter;
    }
}
```

The regular class:

```java
public class LettersClass {
    
    private LettersEnum letter = LettersEnum.A;

    public void setLetter(LettersEnum letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public LettersEnum getLetter() {
        return this.letter;
    }
}
```

I have a video game that has a client and server end. In both ends, `A` is the default letter. If I change `A` to `B` on client end (or vice versa), it will not change the letter on the server side unless I run a packet that encodes the whole enum into a single data type, and decodes on the server side back into the enum.

The problem is, how do I do that? I'm guessing `toString()`, but how would I then convert each value back into the correct data type?

Comment: Is it possible that the enum name is different from the `letter` value of that enum? If not, 1) you don't need `letter`, and 2) you can use `LettersEnum.valueOf`.

Comment: This is just a simplified version of the actual code, The `Letter` value is different to the enum name, I'ved edited it to be more clear.

Answer (score 5):

This is called *serialization*: Turning any random unit of information (in this case, one of your enum values) into serializable data (generally,  bytes, though depending on the underlying transport/storage mechanism, sometimes you must have characters).

There are many ways to do the job. For enums in particular, one particularly obvious way to do this, is to just serialize either the ordinal or the name. Alternatively, you can handroll your own serialization 'key'.

### Ordinals

The 'ordinal' is just the index position in your enum def. In your case, the ordinal of `A` is 0 simply because `A` is the first one you listed. (Not because the `id` field contains 0, that's just a coincidence).

A major problem with serializing via ordinal is that everything breaks if you re-order your enum values or insert a new one in any position except at the end. If you do this, you should definitely add a comment in your code that it is never okay to mess with existing values, you can only add values at the end of the list.

Ordinals have the advantage that they are trivial to send and receive and highly efficient: It's just an int; 32 bits.

##### Convert an enum value to the ordinal

```
LettersEnum letter = LettersEnum.A;
int o = letter.ordinal();
assert o == 0;
```

##### Convert the ordinal back to the enum

```
int o = 0;
LettersEnum letter = LettersEnum.values()[o];
assert letter == LettersEnum.A;
```

The `values()` method is 'magic', all enums just have these, you don't need to write it.

### Names

You can also choose to serialize by way of the enum's name; in this case, `A`, for example. This does let you re-organize your enum in your code, but you can't rename any of the enums if you do this.

A second issue is that serializing strings is slightly more complicated; to do this 'safely', you need to turn your strings into bytes first (as the vast majority of transport/storage mechanisms work in bytes), and you need to make sure you are using UTF-8 encoding when doing so, or you run into problems when you e.g. start adding, say, the letter ß, which is a valid java identifier (`enum Foo { A, B, ß; }` is valid java!).

##### Convert an enum value to the name, then the name to bytes

```
LettersEnum letter = LettersEnum.A;
String name = letter.name();
assert name.equals("A");
byte[] data = name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
assert data.length == 1 && data[0] == 'A';
```

##### Convert the bytes to a string and then to an enum

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {'A'};
String name = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
LettersEnum v = LettersEnum.valueOf(name);
assert v == LettersEnum.A;
```

The `name()` and `valueOf()` methods all just exist, you don't have to write them.

### Your own ID

Both of the above strategies do sort of silently 'link' aspects that we java programmers ordinarily do not consider as having any effect on the runtime behaviour of your program (the order in which you write your fields for ordinal-based serialization, and the value names for name-based), so you or other members of the dev team may rename things and fail to realize that this means anything 'saved' or 'sent' by older code now can no longer be retrieved/received by new code. One easy way out is to use your own ID. This can also be sensible if you are merely modelling an existing concept (say, some third party API that already defines a bunch of commands that have an integer value but nobody likes `.sendCmd(182, ..)`, `.sendCmd(Command.LIST_USERS)` is much nicer.

You sort of have this already - an `id` field.

There is no baked-in support for this, in either direction; you'd have to write it yourself. But this isn't particularly complicated:

```
public enum LettersEnum{

    A(0, “A”),
    B(1, “B”),
    C(2, “C”);

    private final id;
    private final letter;

    LettersEnum(int id, String letter) {
        this.id = id;
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getLetter() {
        return this.letter;
    }

    private static final Map<Integer, LettersEnum> ID_TO_LETTER;
    static {
        var map = new HashMap<Integer, LettersEnum>();
        for (LettersEnum letter : values()) map.put(letter.getId(), letter);
        ID_TO_LETTER = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public static LettersEnum ofId(int id) {
        LettersEnum v = ID_TO_LETTER.get(id);
        if (v != null) return v;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(id + " is not a known LettersEnum id");
    }
}
```

and to use:

```
LettersEnum letter = LettersEnum.A;
int i = letter.getId();
// store i someplace...
```

```
// retrieve o someplace...
int o = 0;
LettersEnum letter = LettersEnum.ofId(o);
assert letter == LettersEnum.A;
```

Answer (score -1):

to get the enum from a Letter would require sth like as a method of your enum:

```
public static LettersEnum getLettersEnum(String s){
            for (LettersEnum l:values()){
                if (l.letter.equals(s)){
                    return l;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
        };
```

If the letter always matches the enum's name, you can get rid of it and always return the name instead of having method `getLetter`. And the loop would then not be necessary, because you could just call `valueOf(String name)` instead of `getLettersEnum(String s)`

Btw. your id and letter fields lack the type.